# How to send pageNumber & pageSize in query parameter - using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, offset, query-string

This my API URL:

```
        {{base_url}}all_department ( GET REQUEST )
```

My controller code:

```
              public function getAllDepartment(Request $request)
{
    $pagination=false;
    $pageNumber=$pageSize="";
    if ($request->has('pageNumber') && $request->has('pageSize')){
        $pagination=true;

        $pageNumber= $request->pageNumber;
        $pageSize= $request->pageSize;
    }
    try
    {
        $department = $this->department;
        $allDepartment = Department::all();

        if ($pagination){
            $offset = ($pageNumber - 1) * $pageSize;
            $results=$department->offset($offset)->limit($pageSize)->orderBy('department_id','DESC')->get();

        }
        else{
            $results=$department->get();
        }
        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'All Department', 'total' => count($allDepartment), 'data' => $results], 200);
    }catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }

}
```

My body request:

```
      {
"pageNumber": 1,
"pageSize": 3
       }
```

What I am trying to do is to sent pageNumber and pageSize in URL like below

```
        {{base_url}}all_department/pageNumber/pageSize
```

How I can do it in parameter instead of body request?

Comment: I think this is what you're after: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters

Comment: make pageNumber and pageSize an optional parameters by specifying it in your route like all_departments/{?pageNumber}/{?pageSize} But this approach might create a problem if you want to access for example to an specific departments like all_departments/{id} not a solid way to do this. I suggest you to use params  like this: all_departments?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`request()->segment(1); or Request::segment(1);`

it will get the first segment in URL so you can change the number to get what you want